# Why will this loop not work with this class that I made?

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, visual-studio, class

So I made this class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// Class for checking if an OrgID already exsists. 

public class AlreadyMade
{
    public int ListOfOrgs { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to make an array from an integer column in a table that I have in an SQL database so that I can use that array to see if that integer already exists or not, and here is that bit of code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
AlreadyMade[] AllOrgs = null;
string CheckQuery = @"SELECT OrgID FROM License";
using (var command = new SqlCommand(CheckQuery, con))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        var list = new List<AlreadyMade>();
        while (reader.Read())
            list.Add(new AlreadyMade {ListOfOrgs = reader.GetInt32(0)});
        AllOrgs = list.ToArray();
    }
}

for (int n = 0; n < AllOrgs.Length; n++)
{
    if (AllOrgs[n].Equals(ID) == true) 
    {
        Found = 1;
    }
}
```

The problem is that it always skips over the

```
        if (AllOrgs[n].Equals(ID) == true)
```

line whether or not the integer I am looking for already exists in the array. It's obvious that I apparently don't understand how the class I made really works, so could someone please help me figure this one out and preferably explain what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Where does that ID come from? is it a parameter?

Comment: wouldn't it be better to do the filtering on your sql server?

Comment: And why are you using `AlreadyMade` at all rather than just creating a `List<int>`?

Comment: ID comes from 
private void UpdateOrganization(int LicensingKey, int ID){

...

}

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, this really should be a `SELECT TOP(1) 1 FROM dbo.License WHERE OrgId = @id` SQL statement and you should just be using `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar` get the constant value back or null if one does not exist. This would eliminate the majority of your code you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing the class object itself with the integer:

```
for (int n = 0; n < AllOrgs.Length; n++)
{
       if (AllOrgs[n].Equals(ID) == true) 
       {
            Found = 1;
       }
}
```

Here

```
if (AllOrgs[n].Equals(ID) == true)
```

You need to compare `ID` with the `integer` inside the object (`ListOfOrgs`):

```
if (AllOrgs[n].ListOfOrgs == ID)
```

or

```
if (AllOrgs[n].ListOfOrgs.Equals(ID))
```

You could archive that by overriding the `Equals` method inside `AlreadyMade`:

```
public class AlreadyMade
{
    public int ListOfOrgs { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var item = (int?)obj;

        if (item == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return this.ListOfOrgs.Equals(item.Value);
    }
}
```

Now when you compare (`Equals`) the `object` with the `ID` you will execute this method.

Comment: Ahhhh I see! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
if( AllOrgs.OfType<AlreadyMade>().ToList().Contains ( new AlreadyMade {ListOfOrgs = ID}) == true)
```

> Try above code, no need to for loop.  sorry for frequent edit, but i there is confusion due to your naming convention.